# Max. Allowable pressure in process pipe

Tags: mechanical-engineering

According to ASME B31.8-2008 to calculate minimum thickness if a pipe under internal pressure you use:
$$t=\dfrac{PD}{2(SEW+PY)}$$

I have seen this formula re-written in terms of pressure of the fluid within the pipe as follows:

$$p(psig)=\dfrac{2t \cdot S \cdot E}{D-2 \cdot t \cdot Y}$$

Assuming that the reduction factor $W=1$, how do they get to the rest of the formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting from one form of the equation to the other involves a little bit of algebraic manipulation and factorisation:

First, assuming $W=1$, multiply both sides of the equation by $2(SE + PY)$:

$$2tSE + 2tPY = PD$$

Then, bring terms that have $P$ in them to one side and factorise:

$$P(D-2tY) = 2tSE$$

Finally, divide by $(D-2tY)$ on both sides:

$$P = \frac{2tSE}{D-2tSE}$$

So, for a given pressure, a minimum thickness is specified. So intuitively, for a given thickness, a maximum pressure should be specified. Therefore, minimum thickness $t$ can be substituted with "given thickness", and simultaneously the given pressure $P$ can be substituted with "maximum pressure", hence giving you the second equation.

A very similar approach is used to obtain the first equation from the second.